# regex - wildcard(*) followed by 2 digit

Tags: regex

I am planning to use RegEx

```
public FirstCharAlphabate_Regex =  /^[a-zA-Z]{2}/
```

Above will help to check first 2 char is alphanumeric
But I wanted to add *(Wild Card) character into it
So when I add wild char than followed 2 digit should be alphanumeric

- s`*`ss  - Valid
- s`*`s - not valid
- ss`*` - valid
- `*`s - not valid
- `*`ss - valid
- ss - valid

I have checked the conditions but did not find the right answer.

Comment: It's best to first state your the question in words, then give your example, showing the desired result (as you have done). Only then should you present the code you have tried and explain why it does not work. "...did not find the right answer." is quite vague, but that's a secondary issue.

Comment: The meaning of *alphanumeric* is "letters or numbers". Your `[a-zA-Z]` will match only letters, not numbers. If that's what you want, it's fine... but it's not alphanumeric.

Comment: Cary Swoveland
Sorry about that. Next time will follow the standard.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is combine multiple patterns with OR `|`

```
^[A-Za-z]{2}|^[A-Za-z]?\*[A-Za-z]{2}
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/waV9m9/1)

I have two patterns:

1. `[A-Za-z]{2}`: Start with (`^`: start of line/string) two alphacharacters `[A-Za-z]{2}`
2. `^[A-Za-z]?\*[A-Za-z]{2}`: Start with an optional (`?`) alphacharacter (as your cases, may change `[A-Za-z]` to `.` to match any character), followed by a `*`, and two alphacharacter. That will match `s*ss` or `*ss`

**Note:** this regex is only able to check the string has the valid format, it wont return a full match. For example: `ss*` is valid, this regex will return *True* but only match `ss`

Comment: Does `^[A-Za-z]?` add anything and is there a reason to have `{2,}` rather than `{2}`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I forget to fix it, already remove `,` in the regex101 demo but forget about the stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can match

```
(?:^|\*)[A-Za-z]{2}
```

This simply matches the start of the string or an asterisk (`(?:^|\*)`), followed by two letters (`[A-Za-z]{2}`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MvMjnH/1)

Comment: Or perhaps `^[A-Za-z]?\*?[A-Za-z]{2}` with 2 optional parts and the anchor.